# Unknown column 'codigo' in 'field list'

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo este php para que me muestre una tabla con los usuarios agregados pero al correr el formulario me marca el error `Unknown column 'codigo' in 'field list'`, en la base de datos el valor código es autoincrementable por lo que no se ingresa al crear un usuario, tuve que desahabilitar el valor `null` en los demás campos por el error `unknow index` pero no se si esto intervenga en algo, tampoco es un problema de conexión con la base porque no marca el texto, he leído acerca del problema pero solo funciono el `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` para evitar lo de `unknow index`.

En la base de datos tienen esto campos sql:

```
CREATE TABLE newuser (
    `codigo` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `apellido` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `informacion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `mail` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `genero` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `suscripcion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

php:

```
<?php
//
if (isset($_REQUEST['pos'])) {
    $inicio = $_REQUEST['pos'];
} else {
    $inicio = 0;
}

//
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Usuarios</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif;
        }

        #page-wrap {
            margin: 50px;
        }

        p {
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

        /*
        Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops
        */
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        /* Zebra striping */
        tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
            background: #eee;
        }
        th {
            background: #333;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        td, th {
            padding: 6px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "usuario");

if ($mysql->connect_error) {
    die("Problemas con la conexión a la base de datos");
}

$registros = $mysql->query("select codigo,nombre,apellido,informacion,mail,password,genero,suscripcion limit 5 offset $inicio;") or
die($mysql->error);

echo '<table class="tablalistado">';
echo '<tr><th>Código</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th><th>Información</th>
        <th>Mail</th><th>Contraseña</th><th>Género</th><th>Suscripción</th><th>Borrar</th></tr>';
//
$impresos = 0;
//

while ($reg = $registros->fetch_array()) {
    //
    $impresos++;
    //
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $reg['codigo'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $reg['nombre'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $reg['apellido'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $reg['informacion'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $reg['mail'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $reg['password'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $reg['genero'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $reg['suscripcion'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a href="baja.php?codigo=' . $reg['codigo'] . '">Borra?</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    //echo '<td>';
    //echo '<a href="modificacionarticulo1.php?codigo='.$reg['codigoart'].'">Modifica?</a>';
    //echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '<tr><td colspan="6">';
echo '<a href="index.html">Nuevo Usuario?</a>';
echo '</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
//

if ($inicio == 0) {
    echo "Anteriores ";
} else {
    $anterior = $inicio - 5;
    echo "<a href=\"usuarioT.php?pos=$anterior\">Anteriores </a>";
}

if ($impresos == 5) {
    $proximo = $inicio + 5;
    echo "<a href=\"usuarioT.php?pos=$proximo\"> Siguientes</a>";
} else {
    echo " Siguientes ";
}
//

$mysql->close();
?>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>alta.php</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "usuario"); //////Aquí pon tu base x2

if ($mysql->connect_error) {
    die("Problemas con la conexión a la base de datos");
}

$txtGenero = "Indefinido";

if ($_REQUEST['genre'] == "fem") {
    $txtGenero = "Femenino";
} else {
    if ($_REQUEST['genre'] == "mas") {
        $txtGenero = "Masculino";
    }
}

$txtSuscripcion = "Normie";
if ($_REQUEST['suscrip'] == "member") {
    $txtSuscripcion = "Miembro";
}

$mysql->query("INSERT INTO
        newuser(nombre,apellido,informacion,mail,password,genero,suscripcion) VALUES
        ('$_REQUEST[name]','$_REQUEST[surname]','$_REQUEST[info]',
        '$_REQUEST[mail]','$_REQUE
        ST[pass]','$txtGenero','$txtSuscripcion')") or die($mysql->error);

$mysql->close();

header('Location:usuarioT.php'); ////Aquí va la página donde cargas la tabla con tus resgistros ya hechos

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: y si le agregas el nombre de la tabla a tu consulta `from tablename`?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu error está en el primer select:

```
registros=$mysql->query("select codigo,nombre,apellido,informacion,mail,password,genero,suscripcion limit 5 offset $inicio;") or die($mysql->error);
```

Por lo que veo, estás seleccionado columnas, pero no estás especificando de qué tabla, un select debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT columna1, columna2 FROM tabla WHERE columna 1 = valor LIMIT 5"
```

En donde "FROM tabla" es el nombre de la tabla de donde seleccionarás las columnas.

Comment: funciona pero no me guarda ningun dato y si le quito el error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE) me vuelve a marcar el error unknow index

Comment: Edit: No me había dado cuenta que si tenías el validador. Acabo de probar tu código y funciona bien (agregando el FROM tabla), pero no veo ningún form para rellenar información para enviar luego a REQUEST, sería ideal que uses POST en vez de REQUEST. Y tengas un script separado para insertar datos.